# Which brake arms of Shimano XTR M900 go in front?

Tags: shimano, brakes

The Shimano XTR BR-M900 Cantilever brake arms come in two different lengths. Which go in front, the long ones with the stamped "F" or the shorter ones?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have two sets of two, and the picture shows one of each?

In that case the pair marked **F** would be front-brake.  The longer brake arm gives you more mechanical advantage on the wheel where it helps the most.

If you have a single pair and they're mismatched in length, then something's wrong and two pairs have been mixed up.

Comment: Yes, I do have the other two corresponding arms as well.

Comment: @user430 to be honest I can't see a reason why you couldn't use the arms marked F on the rear, or vise versa.  Having both arms the same length is definitely going to make the yoke cable's action more simple.